# Problem with responsive in carousel class, HTML CSS

Tags: html, css, angular, templates, responsive

I am using this template:
https://codepen.io/xweronika/pen/abBdXGp

I created several components like this, in which instead of text there are also tables, buttons and many elements. When it's full screen everything looks fine:

[image]

But when I reduce size of the window - text inside "cut off" and the scroll is blocked, so I can't scroll down to see the rest of the text:

[image]

And when I reduce the size of the window even more - the text completely disappears:

[image]

Please help me, this looks terrible :(

HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Mouri</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" 
      data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" 
      aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Portfolio</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Services</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://i.postimg.cc/bNQp0RDW/1.jpg" alt="First slide">
      <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
        <h5>Slider One Item</h5>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Maxime, nulla, tempore. Deserunt excepturi quas vero.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Maxime, nulla, tempore. Deserunt excepturi quas vero.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Maxime, nulla, tempore. Deserunt excepturi quas vero.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://i.postimg.cc/pVzg3LWn/2.jpg" alt="Second slide">
      <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
        <h5>Slider One Item</h5>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Maxime, nulla, tempore. Deserunt excepturi quas vero.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Maxime, nulla, tempore. Deserunt excepturi quas vero.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Maxime, nulla, tempore. Deserunt excepturi quas vero.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://i.postimg.cc/0y2F6Gpp/3.jpg" alt="Third slide">
      <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
        <h5>Slider One Item</h5>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Maxime, nulla, tempore. Deserunt excepturi quas vero.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Maxime, nulla, tempore. Deserunt excepturi quas vero.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Maxime, nulla, tempore. Deserunt excepturi quas vero.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.carousel-item {
  height: 100vh;
  min-height: 300px;
  background: no-repeat center center scroll;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
.carousel-caption {
  top: 190px;
}

.carousel-caption h5 {
  font-size: 45px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  margin-top: 25px;
}

.carousel-caption p {
  width: 75%;
  margin: auto;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 1.9;
}

.navbar-light .navbar-brand {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}

.navbar-light .navbar-nav .active > .nav-link, .navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link.active, .navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link.show, .navbar-light .navbar-nav .show > .nav-link {
  color: #fff;
}

.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link {
  color: #fff;
}

.navbar-toggler {
  background: #fff;
}

.navbar-nav {
  text-align: center;
}

.nav-link {
  padding: .2rem 1rem;
}

.nav-link.active,.nav-link:focus{
  color: #fff;
}

.navbar-toggler {
  padding: 1px 5px;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 0.3;
}

.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link:focus, .navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link:hover {
  color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: In addition to @gionic answer. Also, adjust the height to `img` (inside `.d-block`), and adjust the top rules to `.carousel-caption`.

Comment: @s.kuznetsov  Can you say something more? Or give some example? I do not understand what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `d-none` class from `<div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">`

Check the example [here](https://codepen.io/gionic/pen/yLVewXg)

Display property bootstrap 4 doc [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/display/)

Comment: Thank you. It is much better. But is anything else that can be done? With blocked scroll or when text is cut off?

Comment: Well, I see that your elements have `position: absolute` and `carousel-caption` class has `top: 190px;` I believe you must add media queries to your css and change `top` value

Comment: I don't see the properties `position: absolute` anywhere. What do you mean? And what do you mean about media queries? When I remove `top: 190px;` then text is at the bottom and looks bad.

Comment: Please read What is a Media Query from here https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp
And check again my example here
https://codepen.io/gionic/pen/yLVewXg

Comment: Unfortunately, I still haven't found `position: absolute`. But I read about Media Query and I used it. And it looks much better now. Thank you!

Comment: In my codepen you can see a media query example. Please check the answer. Good luck with your project :)

Answer (score 2):

The `d-none` class inside below HTML element is causing the issue. Remove it from all three elements.

```
<div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
```

Check the below css being applied from the library you added.
[Check the highlighted area in image: .d#{$infix}-none](https://i.stack.imgur.com/97drw.png)

Comment: Thank you. Without `d-none` is better. 
What do you mean about `display: none important!;`? In which class could I use it? 
And could you correct something more? For example with blocked scroll when text is cut off?